# List not storing item properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, repeater

I am trying to do like from the collapsible panel extender, I select few rows by checking the checkbox. After I marked them checked and click the add button, I store them into a list and display the added item in a gridview. After that, I went to another gridview which I setup using repeater, I select another few items, then it will be added into the list and the previously added items will still be there. Here is how I setup my gridview using repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <!-- COLLAPSIBLE PANEL EXTENDER -->
                                <asp:Panel ID="pHeader1" runat="server" CssClass="cpHeader">
                                    <!-- Collapsible panel extender header -->
                                    <div class="form-group" style="background-color: #ffb848; height: 30px; vertical-align: middle">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div style="float: left; color: White; padding: 5px 5px 0 0">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblProduct" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name") %>' runat="server" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div style="float: right; color: White; padding: 5px 5px 0 0">
                                                <asp:Label ID="lblHeaderText1" runat="server" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="clear: both"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </asp:Panel>
                                <!-- Collapsible panel extender body -->
                                <asp:Panel ID="pBody1" runat="server" CssClass="cpBody">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblBodyText1" runat="server" />
                                    <!-- Grid view to show products based on each category -->
                                    <asp:GridView ID="gvProduct" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="740px" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="False" DataKeyNames="id">
                                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbCheckRow" runat="server" ItemStyle-Width="50px" />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="50px" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="550px" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="halal" HeaderText="Halal" ItemStyle-Width="50px" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="unitQuantity" HeaderText="Unit Quantity" />
                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                    <br />
                                </asp:Panel>
                                <asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="cpe1" runat="server" TargetControlID="pBody1" CollapseControlID="pHeader1"
                                    ExpandControlID="pHeader1" Collapsed="true" TextLabelID="lblHeaderText1" CollapsedText="Show"
                                    ExpandedText="Hide" CollapsedSize="0"
                                    ScrollContents="false">
                                </asp:CollapsiblePanelExtender>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Panel ID="pBody2" runat="server" CssClass="cpBody">
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvFinalised" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="740px" DataKeyNames="id">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="categoryName" HeaderText="Category" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Product" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="inventoryQuantity" HeaderText="Storage Level" />
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="unitQuantity" HeaderText="Unit Quantity" />
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="200px">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbQuantity" runat="server" Width="40" Text="0" OnTextChanged="tbQuantity_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblCheckAmount" runat="server" ForeColor="#a94442"></asp:Label>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>

                            </asp:GridView>
                        </asp:Panel>
```

There are two gridviews. One inside a repeater which show the product and product variants. Another one is outside the repeater which shows the item added into it. And the code behind:

```
protected void lbnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<ProductPacking> prodVariantDetail = new List<ProductPacking>();

        foreach (RepeaterItem ri in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            GridView gvProduct = (GridView)ri.FindControl("gvProduct");
            foreach (GridViewRow gr in gvProduct.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.FindControl("cbCheckRow");
                if (cb.Checked)
                {
                    // add the corresponding DataKey to idList
                    prodVariantIDList.Add(gvProduct.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < prodVariantIDList.Count; i++)
        {
            Label1.Text += prodVariantIDList[i];
            prodVariantDetail.Add(prodPackBLL.getProdVariantDetailByID(prodVariantIDList[i]));

        }
        gvFinalised.DataSource = prodVariantDetail;
        gvFinalised.DataBind();
    }
```

My problem is let's say I select product variant 1,2,3 which is under canned food category. Then I went to another category and select product variant 4,5,6. The 4,5,6 which is the latest action will be displayed in the gridview but not the 1,2,3. I wonder how to fix this? Do I need something like temp list to store it?

Thanks in advance.

Edited Portion

```
private List<ProductPacking> prodVariantDetail
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["prodVariantDetail"] == null)
            {
                return new List<ProductPacking>();
            }
            else
            {
                return (List<ProductPacking>)ViewState["prodVariantDetail"];
            }
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["prodVariantDetail"] = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: When you `select product variant 1,2,3` and `select product variant 4,5,6`, is it executing `lbnAdd_Click` twice?

Comment: @ekad Yup twice. But the list just store the last execution

Comment: Do I need a viewState for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `prodVariantIDList` will always be empty when `lbnAdd_Click` is executed, so you need to keep the previously selected product variant ids between postbacks. I'd suggest using ViewState to store the content of `prodVariantIDList`.

**EDIT**

After looking at the edited portion, you can't store `List<ProductPacking>` in ViewState if `ProductPacking` class is not serializable. I'd suggest a simpler solution. First change the property:

```
private List<string> SelectedVariantDetailIDs
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["SelectedVariantDetailIDs"] == null)
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }
        else
        {
            return (List<string>)ViewState["SelectedVariantDetailIDs"];
        }
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["SelectedVariantDetailIDs"] = value;
    }
}
```

then in `lbnAdd_Click`:

```
protected void lbnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ProductPacking> prodVariantDetail = new List<ProductPacking>();

    // get the last product variant IDs from ViewState
    prodVariantIDList = this.SelectedVariantDetailIDs;

    foreach (RepeaterItem ri in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        GridView gvProduct = (GridView)ri.FindControl("gvProduct");
        foreach (GridViewRow gr in gvProduct.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.FindControl("cbCheckRow");
            if (cb.Checked)
            {
                // add the corresponding DataKey to idList
                prodVariantIDList.Add(gvProduct.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < prodVariantIDList.Count; i++)
    {
        Label1.Text += prodVariantIDList[i];
        prodVariantDetail.Add(prodPackBLL.getProdVariantDetailByID(prodVariantIDList[i]));
    }
    gvFinalised.DataSource = prodVariantDetail;
    gvFinalised.DataBind();

    // save prodVariantIDList to ViewState
    this.SelectedVariantDetailIDs = prodVariantIDList;
}
```

Comment: I added the viewState (see edited portion) but it does not work.

Comment: `prodVariantDetail` in `lbnAdd_Click` refers to a local variable instead of the new property. You have to remove this line in `lbnAdd_Click`: `List<ProductPacking> prodVariantDetail = new List<ProductPacking>();`, otherwise the property won't be updated.

Comment: But if I removed it, when I click add, no records added into the list. It just remains empty

Comment: u there? do u know how to fix this?

Comment: What if you rename the property to let's say `SelectedVariantDetails`, then add this line at the end of `lbnAdd_Click`: `this.SelectedVariantDetails = prodVariantDetail;`, and change the first line to `List<ProductPacking> prodVariantDetail = this.SelectedVariantDetails;`?

Comment: It return me an error message: Type 'FoodBankObjects.Donations.ProductPacking' in Assembly 'FoodBankObjects, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

Comment: Unfortunately nope, it still not added into the list

Comment: Yeah it works. But would you mind to give me a short brief on the solution?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45806/discussion-between-ekad-and-gwen)

Comment: Would you mind to help me solve another problem with viewState? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362852/gridview-missing-data-when-postback